# Looking for a "weighted average if" functions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am familiar with the `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED` function in Google Sheets, but I'm wondering if there's a way to add an IF in there, like `=AVERAGEIF`.  I have a baseball spreadsheet, with the following columns:

**Column A** - Player Name, **Column B** - Team, **Column C** - Innings Played, **Column D** - Batting Average

Basically, I want a weighted average of batting averages of all players on certain team, using innings played as the weights. If I used `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(D:D, C:C)`, I would get a nice weighted average of all batting averages with innings played as the weights, but I only want to include players who have a Team of *Yankees*. How could I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=Team);D:D;C:C)/SUMIF(B:B;TEAM;C:C)` worked for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found one way to accomplish this! I added a **Column E** which is Innings Played multiplied by Batting Average (`Column C * Column D`). Then, I can use a `=SUMIF` to sum results in column E if Column B shows a certain team, and divide that by another `=SUMIF` that sums Column C if Column B shows that same team. `=SUMIF(B:B, "Yankees", E:E)/SUMIF(B:B, "Yankees", C:C)`. Just wanted to post this answer in case anyone else is looking for the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(IF(B:B=Team,D:D),IF(B:B=Team,C:C)))
```